# Can I redirect an ifstream to cin?

Tags: c++, ifstream

I have a program that reads input from the terminal and the stream from `cin` is used in multiple classes for parsing at various levels.

Instead of using `cin` for getting the data from the terminal, I want to read in a file that has the information I need to parse, but I don't want to modify all my header and .cpp files to accept an `ifstream&` parameter.

To keep the existing code in place I'm trying to simply redirect the `ifstream` to cin, but don't know how.

So assume I have the following in main:

```
ifstream inFile("myfile.txt", ifstream::io);

string line;
while(getline(inFile, line)) 
{
  char firstChar;
  inFile >> firstChar;
  cout << firstChar;
  inFile.ios::rdbuf(cin.rdbuf());
  Continue myFile;
}
```

In my `continue.cpp` I'm just doing:

```
Continue()
{
   string line;
   cin >> line;
   cout << "---remaining line: " << line << "\n";
}
```

However it's only printing the first char from main.

Comment: "but I don't want to modify all my header and .cpp files to accept an ifstream& parameter." That's unfortunate.

Comment: @AmiTavory ahh ok, so no way around it?

Comment: Yes it is. Take a look at dup and dup2 function (prefix with `_` for Windows) . I'm just searching for an example.

Comment: @free_mind There's probably some hack around it. Nevertheless, the most straightforward thing is just to express in the code that you're working with some (subclass) object of istream. I personally think that dupping and stuff just obscures this.

Comment: @free_mind You really should decouple your classes from ``std::cin``. While you’re at it, you can make them use ``std::istream`` instead of ``std::ifstream`` for reading—that way you can use both, ``std::cin`` and ``std::ifstream``.

Comment: Can't you use input redirection at OS level? your-exec <myfile.txt will get input from myfile.txt

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply swap pointers to `std::streambuf`:

```
ifstream file("myfile.txt");
string line;
if (file.is_open()) {
    cin.rdbuf(file.rdbuf());  // swap
    cin >> line;
}
std::cout << line;
```

Comment: I think this will do it, but I'm getting an error `std::istream' has no member named 'set_rdbuf'

Comment: As you can probably tell, I'm new to c++ :-P

Comment: I just changed it to `cin.rdbuf(file.rdbuf())` and that worked!  thanks so much

Comment: I'm on Windows, VS 2012. `rdbuf` works for me too. Maybe this solution is more multiplatform.

Comment: According to the comment in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56707751/12452330) answer, if you are trying to do the reverse and set an **ifstream** streambuf to **cin**, then you have to prefix the full namespace and class for the `rdbuf(/* another rdbuf */)` method to be found, i.e. use `file.std::istream::rdbuf(cin.rdbuf())`. Just calling the method directly from an ifstream will cause a compile error.

Answer (score 4):

`istream` objects read from a `std::streambuf`, and that can be swapped in an out. The relevant member function is `.rdbuf`

Answer (score 2):

You can also redirect the underlying C `stdin` file handle to a different file, this will also affect your `cin`:

```
freopen ("myfile.txt", "r", stdin);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very quick and easy way to do it.

If your file is called "file.txt", the code would be:

```
fstream cin("file.txt");
```

This way, everything that's from the file would be redirected to cin >>