# Error calling both set_rdbuf and rdbuf on std::ifstream

Tags: c++

Below is some code I wrote in c++.

```
ifstream objfile(s1.c_str());

string s2 = strfile; 
std::istringstream objstr(s2);
if (path.empty())  objfile.set_rdbuf(objstr.rdbuf());
```

It has no problem compile in Visual Studio C++ 2017. When I try to compile using g++ in redhat linux, it has error

`error: ‘std::ifstream’ has no member named ‘set_rdbuf’`

Edit: Based on the initial answers to this question, I tried replacing the call to `set_rdbuf` with

```
objfile.rdbuf(objstr.rdbuf());
```

This still does not work. It says

`rdbuf() const, note: candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided.`

The full error messages is really long, I removed the lines of In files included from ...

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_ifstream<char>::rdbuf(std::basic_istringstream<char>::__stringbuf_type*)’
   if(path.empty())  objfile.rdbuf(objstr.rdbuf());
                                                 ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/fstream:509:7: note: std::basic_ifstream<_CharT, _Traits>::__filebuf_type* std::basic_ifstream<_CharT, _Traits>::rdbuf() const [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ifstream<_CharT, _Traits>::__filebuf_type = std::basic_filebuf<char>]
       rdbuf() const
       ^

       error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_ifstream<char>::rdbuf(std::basic_istringstream<char>::__stringbuf_type*)’
   if (path.empty())  objfile.rdbuf(objstr.rdbuf());
                                                  ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/fstream:509:7: note: std::basic_ifstream<_CharT, _Traits>::__filebuf_type* std::basic_ifstream<_CharT, _Traits>::rdbuf() const [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ifstream<_CharT, _Traits>::__filebuf_type = std::basic_filebuf<char>]
       rdbuf() const
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/fstream:509:7: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided

/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ext/new_allocator.h: In instantiation of ‘void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::construct(_Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = std::basic_istringstream<char>; _Args = {std::basic_istringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >}; _Tp = std::basic_istringstream<char>]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/alloc_traits.h:254:4:   required from ‘static typename std::enable_if<std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::__construct_helper<_Tp, _Args>::value, void>::type std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::_S_construct(_Alloc&, _Tp*, _Args&& ...) [with _Tp = std::basic_istringstream<char>; _Args = {std::basic_istringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >}; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::basic_istringstream<char> >; typename std::enable_if<std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::__construct_helper<_Tp, _Args>::value, void>::type = void]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/alloc_traits.h:393:57:   required from ‘static decltype (_S_construct(__a, __p, (forward<_Args>)(std::allocator_traits::construct::__args)...)) std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::construct(_Alloc&, _Tp*, _Args&& ...) [with _Tp = std::basic_istringstream<char>; _Args = {std::basic_istringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >}; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::basic_istringstream<char> >; decltype (_S_construct(__a, __p, (forward<_Args>)(std::allocator_traits::construct::__args)...)) = <type error>]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/vector.tcc:97:40:   required from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::emplace_back(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {std::basic_istringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >}; _Tp = std::basic_istringstream<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::basic_istringstream<char> >]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_vector.h:920:36:   required from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type&&) [with _Tp = std::basic_istringstream<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::basic_istringstream<char> >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = std::basic_istringstream<char>]’
/home/research/QZ/6_compile_Agency_Model/Agency_files/BondModel/utility.h:2413:37:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ext/new_allocator.h:120:4: error: use of deleted function ‘std::basic_istringstream<char>::basic_istringstream(const std::basic_istringstream<char>&)’
  { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
    ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/complex:45:0,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/detail/container_fwd.hpp:98,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/container_hash/extensions.hpp:22,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/container_hash/hash.hpp:760,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/type_index/stl_type_index.hpp:42,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/type_index.hpp:29,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/any.hpp:20,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/program_options/value_semantic.hpp:12,
                 from /home/research/boost_library/boost_1_68_0/boost/program_options/options_description.hpp:13,

/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/sstream:272:11: note: ‘std::basic_istringstream<char>::basic_istringstream(const std::basic_istringstream<char>&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
     class basic_istringstream : public basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>
           ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/sstream:272:11: error: use of deleted function ‘std::basic_istream<char>::basic_istream(const std::basic_istream<char>&)’


/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/istream:58:11: note: ‘std::basic_istream<char>::basic_istream(const std::basic_istream<char>&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
     class basic_istream : virtual public basic_ios<_CharT, _Traits>
           ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/istream:58:11: error: use of deleted function ‘std::basic_ios<char>::basic_ios(const std::basic_ios<char>&)’


/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/basic_ios.h:66:11: note: ‘std::basic_ios<char>::basic_ios(const std::basic_ios<char>&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
     class basic_ios : public ios_base
           ^


/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/ios_base.h:786:5: error: ‘std::ios_base::ios_base(const std::ios_base&)’ is private
     ios_base(const ios_base&);
     ^

/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/basic_ios.h:66:11: error: within this context
     class basic_ios : public ios_base
           ^

/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/sstream:272:11: error: use of deleted function ‘std::basic_ios<char>::basic_ios(const std::basic_ios<char>&)’
     class basic_istringstream : public basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>
           ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/sstream:272:11: error: use of deleted function ‘std::basic_stringbuf<char>::basic_stringbuf(const std::basic_stringbuf<char>&)’
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/sstream:64:11: note: ‘std::basic_stringbuf<char>::basic_stringbuf(const std::basic_stringbuf<char>&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
     class basic_stringbuf : public basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>
           ^

/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/streambuf:802:7: error: ‘std::basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_streambuf(const std::basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]’ is private
       basic_streambuf(const basic_streambuf& __sb)
       ^

/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/sstream:64:11: error: within this context
     class basic_stringbuf : public basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>
           ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/vector:62:0,

/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_construct.h: In instantiation of ‘void std::_Construct(_T1*, _Args&& ...) [with _T1 = std::basic_istringstream<char>; _Args = {std::basic_istringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >}]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:75:53:   required from ‘static _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy<_TrivialValueTypes>::__uninit_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = std::move_iterator<std::basic_istringstream<char>*>; _ForwardIterator = std::basic_istringstream<char>*; bool _TrivialValueTypes = false]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:117:41:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::uninitialized_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = std::move_iterator<std::basic_istringstream<char>*>; _ForwardIterator = std::basic_istringstream<char>*]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:258:63:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::allocator<_Tp>&) [with _InputIterator = std::move_iterator<std::basic_istringstream<char>*>; _ForwardIterator = std::basic_istringstream<char>*; _Tp = std::basic_istringstream<char>]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:281:69:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_move_if_noexcept_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, _Allocator&) [with _InputIterator = std::basic_istringstream<char>*; _ForwardIterator = std::basic_istringstream<char>*; _Allocator = std::allocator<std::basic_istringstream<char> >]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/vector.tcc:415:43:   required from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_emplace_back_aux(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {std::basic_istringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >}; _Tp = std::basic_istringstream<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::basic_istringstream<char> >]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/vector.tcc:101:54:   required from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::emplace_back(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {std::basic_istringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >}; _Tp = std::basic_istringstream<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::basic_istringstream<char> >]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_vector.h:920:36:   required from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type&&) [with _Tp = std::basic_istringstream<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::basic_istringstream<char> >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = std::basic_istringstream<char>]’
/home/research/QZ/6_compile_Agency_Model/Agency_files/BondModel/utility.h:2413:37:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_construct.h:75:7: error: use of deleted function ‘std::basic_istringstream<char>::basic_istringstream(const std::basic_istringstream<char>&)’
     { ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
       ^
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/BondModel.dir/cashflowengine.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/BondModel.dir/all] Error 2
```

Comment: Can you post the exact error message you're getting? What you've posted sounds like a part of a larger series of error messages.

Comment: @templatetypedef the full error message is added. Thanks so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite interesting. As others have noted, the initial issue here is that the `set_rdbuf` member function is protected, so you can’t call it directly. I was surprised when you reported that calling the correct member function `rdbuf` didn’t compile, because that member function does exist and is public.

The short version is that I believe the following code will do what you want:

```
if (path.empty())  objfile.istream::rdbuf(objstr.rdbuf());
```

The reason you need the `istream::` prefix here has to do with how C++ does name lookups in derived classes. If a derived class declares a member function with a given name and you try to call a function with that name, the compiler will not look to base classes to find potential overloads for that function. In C++11, the `ifstream` type had a new helper function added called `rdbuf` that returns the underlying buffer as a `filebuf*`. This shadows the `istream` function `rdbuf` that sets the underlying buffer. As a result, if call the one-argument version of `rdbuf`, C++ won’t find it because it stops searching as soon as it finds the zero-argument `rdbuf` defined in `ifstream`. Adding the explicit `istream::rdbuf` call tells the compiler to search for this function in `istream` first, where it ends up finding the function you want.

Hope this helps!

Comment: this works in a separate code. In my project, it still has error messages. I suspect this may be because my compiler (gcc 8.2) and include file does not match ( /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/). Anyway, this is out of the scope of this post. I try to upvote but does not have enough reputation. Thanks so much

Comment: For those not fluent with this kind of notations, don't forget to precise **all** the namespace chain: `objfile.std::istream::rdbuf(objstr.rdbuf())`

Answer (score 0):

`std::ifstream::set_rdbuf` is protected, as mentioned [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/set_rdbuf). It's possible that MSVC exposes it as a public member function in `std::ifstream` which would explain why your code compiles there.

What you want is [`rdbuf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/rdbuf):

> `std::basic_streambuf<CharT, Traits>* rdbuf( std::basic_streambuf<CharT, Traits>* sb );`
>
> Sets the associated stream buffer to sb. The error state is cleared by calling clear(). Returns the associated stream buffer before the operation. If there is no associated stream buffer, returns a null pointer.

Comment: I tried objfile.rdbuf(objstr.rdbuf());, it does not work. It says  rdbuf() const,  note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided.

Comment: This does not compile

Comment: @A.Gille See the accepted answer. It does work, you just need to specify the right one.

Comment: @Kevin, Yes, so what I say is true. Your answer does not work therefore is not a solution.

Comment: @A.Gille I posted a link to the function you need to use. I didn't post code showing it being used. Admittedly I wasn't aware of `std::ifstream::rdbuf()`, but regardless, what part of my answer is incorrect?

Comment: @Kevin You're right, I misread the rdbuf overload you mentioned. You can disregard my comments.

Answer (score 0):

[set_rdbuf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/set_rdbuf) is a protected member function. That is why it is not accessible.